# Copy Paste on pin text field in flutter not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, uitextfield, textfield, copy-paste

I have a PIN text field in flutter and I'm trying to paste the code in text field. However, only in the first text field is the code pasted and not in the others.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sNYW.png)

Comment: Can you share the code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pin_code_fields library [link](https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields)

Code Snippet:

```
PinCodeTextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        appContext: context,
        length: 6,
        obscureText: false,
        dialogConfig: DialogConfig(
          dialogContent: "Do you want to paste ",
          dialogTitle: "Paste OTP",
        ),
        pastedTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        pinTheme: PinTheme(
          inactiveColor: Colors.black45,
          selectedColor: Colors.green,
          shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          fieldHeight: 50,
          fieldWidth: 40,
          activeFillColor: Colors.white,
        ),

        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {});
        },
        onCompleted: (pin) {
          setState(() {});

        },
        beforeTextPaste: () {
          return true;
        },
```

Alter the **dialogConfig** and **pastedTextStyle** property for more flexibility during pasting the otp

For more Detailed example use the following [github_link](https://github.com/adar2378/pin_code_fields)